# How to set two yAxis for two series first on right second in left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I tried to get the each yAxis a side (right/left) but I had no luck.
I fount some solutions for 'https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js' but doesnt work with 'http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js'. It seems that highstock.js does not use the same config as highchart.js

the code is available here https://jsfiddle.net/ddidd/k3tndba9/3/

```
Highcharts.chart('chart_container') has some solutions --- Highcharts.stockChart('chart_container') has not
```

Answer (score 0):

Highstock sets `opposite: true` for y-axis by default. To have y-axes for both sides set `opposite: false` for one of them.

```
    yAxis: [{
      ...,
      opposite: false
    }, {
      ...,
      opposite: true
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1qjg8kxu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.opposite